# convert list to dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, dictionary, iterator

I am new to Pythonland and I have a question. I have a list as below and want to convert it into a dataframe.

I read on Stackoverflow that it is better to create a dictionary then a list so I create one as follows.

```
column_names = ["name", "height" , "weight", "grade"] # Actual list has 10 entries

row_names = ["jack", "mick", "nick","pick"]

data = ['100','50','A','107','62','B'] # The actual list has 1640 entries

dic = {key:[] for key in column_names}
dic['name'] = row_names
t = 0
while t< len(data):
    dic['height'].append(data[t])
    t = t+3
t = 1
while t< len(data):
    dic['weight'].append(data[t])
    t = t+3
```

So on and so forth, I have 10 columns so I wrote above code 10 times to complete the full dictionary. Then i convert
it to dataframe. It works perfectly fine, there has to
be a way to do this in shorter way. I don't know how to refer to key of a dictionary with a number. Should it be wrapped to a function. Also, how can I automate adding one to value of t before executing the next loop? Please help me.

Comment: you're missing a few quotation marks in your example row/column names. also, i think i understand the disconnect, looking at how your data is created. The way the question most likely recommended a dict be created, is by data being in logical groups of *columns*, that's usually how we should think of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `columnn_names` like this:

```
dic = {key:[] for key in column_names}
dic['name'] = row_names
for t, column_name in enumerate(column_names):
    i = t
    while i< len(data):
        dic[column_name].append(data[i])
        i += 3
```

Enumerate will automatically iterate through `t` form 0 to `len(column_names)-1`

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but above code will enumerate over the key 'name' as well , hence desired output is not achieved.

Comment: So you can exclude that from the list that you'll be iterating over.
    `for t, column_name in enumerate(column_names[1:]):`

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        for j in column_names:
            d[j].append(data[i])
            i += 1

    except Exception as er:  #So when i value exceed by data list it comes to exception and it will break the loop as well
        print(er, "################")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that you have all columns data concatenated to a single list. You should first investigate how to prevent it and have list of lists with each column values in a separate list like `[['100', '107'], ['50', '62'], ['A', 'B']]`. Any way you need this data structure to proceed efficiently:

```
cl_count = len(column_names)
d_count = len(data)
spl_data = [[data[j] for j in range(i, d_count, cl_count)] for i in range(cl_count)]
```

Then you should use dict comprehension. **This is a 3.x Python feature** so it will not work in Py 2.x.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({j: spl_data[i] for i, j in enumerate(column_names)})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we should understand how an ideal dictionary for a dataframe should look like.

A Dataframe can be thought of in two different ways:
One is a traditional **collection of rows..**

```
'row 0':  ['jack', 100, 50, 'A'],
'row 1':  ['mick', 107, 62, 'B']
```

However, there is a second representation that is more useful, though perhaps not as intuitive at first.
**A collection of columns:**

```
'name': ['jack', 'mick'],
'height': ['100', '107'],
'weight': ['50', '62'],
'grade': ['A', 'B']
```

Now, here is the key thing to realise, the 2nd representation is more useful 
because that is the representation interally supported and used in dataframes.
It does not run into conflict of datatype within a single grouping (each column needs to have 1 fixed datatype)
Across a row representation however, datatypes can vary.
Also, operations can be performed easily and consistently on an entire column
because of this consistency that cant be guaranteed in a row.

So, **tl;dr** DataFrames are essentially collections of equal length columns.

So, a dictionary in that representation can be easily converted into a DataFrame.

```
column_names = ["name", "height" , "weight", "grade"] # Actual list has 10 entries

row_names = ["jack", "mick"]

data = [100, 50,'A', 107, 62,'B'] # The actual list has 1640 entries
```

So, With that in mind, the first thing to realize is that, in its current format, **`data` is a very poor representation.**
It is a collection of rows merged into a single list.

The first thing to do, if you're the one in control of how data is formed, is to not prepare it this way.

The goal is a list for each column, and ideally, prepare the list in that format.

Now, however, if it is given in  this format, you need to iterate and collect the values accordingly. Here's a way to do it

```
column_names = ["name", "height" , "weight", "grade"] # Actual list has 10 entries
row_names = ["jack", "mick"]
data = [100, 50,'A', 107, 62,'B'] # The actual list has 1640 entries

dic = {key:[] for key in column_names}
dic['name'] = row_names
print(dic)
```

Output so far:

```
{'height': [],
 'weight': [],
 'grade': [],
 'name': ['jack', 'mick']} #so, now, names are a column representation with all correct values.

remaining_cols = column_names[1:]

#Explanations for the following part given at the end
data_it = iter(data)
for row in zip(*([data_it] * len(remaining_cols))):
    for i, val in enumerate(row):
        dic[remaining_cols[i]].append(val)

print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'name': ['jack', 'mick'],
 'height': [100, 107],
 'weight': [50, 62],
 'grade': ['A', 'B']}
```

And we are done with the representation

Finally:

```
import pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dic, columns = column_names)
print(df)
   name  height  weight grade
0  jack     100      50     A
1  mick     107      62     B
```

Edit: 
Some explanation for the zip part:
`zip` takes any iterables and allows us through iterate through them together.

```
data_it = iter(data) #prepares an iterator. 

[data_it] * len(remaining_cols) #creates references to the same iterator
```

Here, this is similar to `[data_it, data_it, data_it]`

The `*` in `*[data_it, data_it, data_it]` allows us to unpack the list into 3 arguments for the zip function instead
so, `f(*[data_it, data_it, data_it])` is equivalent to `f(data_it, data_it, data_it)` for any function f.

the magic here is that traversing through an iterator/advancing an iterator will now reflect the change across all references

Putting it all together:
`zip(*([data_it] * len(remaining_cols)))` will actually allow us to take 3 items from data at a time, and assign it to row
So, `row = (100, 50, 'A')` in first iteration of zip

```
for i, val in enumerate(row): #just iterate through the row, keeping index too using enumerate
    dic[remaining_cols[i]].append(val) #use indexes to access the correct list in the dictionary
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.x, as suggested by [l159](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956212/5359797), you can use a comprehension dict and then create a Pandas DataFrame out of it, using the names as row indexes:

```
data = ['100', '50', 'A', '107', '62', 'B', '103', '64', 'C', '105', '78', 'D']
column_names = ["height", "weight", "grade"]
row_names = ["jack", "mick", "nick", "pick"]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        row_label: {
            column_label: data[i * len(column_names) + j]
            for j, column_label in enumerate(column_names)
        } for i, row_label in enumerate(row_names)
    },
    orient='index'
)
```

Actually, the intermediate dictionary is a nested dictionary: the keys of the outer dictionary are the row labels (in this case the items of the `row_names` list); the value associated with each key is a dictionary whose keys are the column labels (i.e., the items in `column_names`) and values are the correspondent elements in the `data` list.

The function [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) is used to create the DataFrame instance.

So, the previous code produces the following result:

```
     height weight grade
jack    100     50     A
mick    107     62     B
nick    103     64     C
pick    105     78     D
```